# how to specify multiple file extensions and open it in separate buffer

Tags: find-file

To find files by multiple file extensions I use in Linux smt like this (in terminal):

```
find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.txt -o -iname \*.json \)
```

And here result:

```
./test.txt
./project_1_1/test.json
./project_1_1/test1_1.txt
./project_1_2/test_1.2.txt
```

Nice.
But what about Emacs? Is it possible in Emacs to find files with multiple file extensions and open result in separate buffer?
I need this because then I want to delete all find files.

Comment: You can run that exact shell command using `M-!`.

Comment: as in `find-file` to open them all in emacs?

Comment: @NickD I need then  to open result in separate buffer

Comment: What does that mean? The "result" is the list. So do you want to have the list in a separate buffer? Do you wnant to be able to choose some files from the list and open them in separate buffers?  Open every file in the list in separate buffers? In the latter case, have you thought about what would happen if the list consists of thousands of files? In any case, please modify the question and describe exactly what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Would `M-x find-name-dired` be enough?

Comment: @NickD I was edit my post

Comment: If you don't know about the `-exec` option or the `-execdir` option of `find` (both with the `;` and the `+` suffix), you should find out about them. You should also probably become familiar with `xargs`. OTOH, if you want to learn some Elisp, @shynur's answer contains a bunch of things that you probably want to learn. But the quickest and safest way to a solution to your problem is to add `-execdir rm '{} \+` to your `find` command. BTW, I would always run the initial `find` command first to make sure that it is picking up *only* files you want removed. Then run it with `-execdir ...`.

Comment: Correction: missing quote in the `execdir` option:  `-execdir rm '{}' \+`.

Comment: @ManuelUberti Not enough. It can't find files with differents extenstions

Comment: True, you can use `find-dired` with the args you prefer, e.g., `-name \*.json -o -name \*.txt`.

Comment: @ManuelUberti Yes, this help:  find-dired -name \*.json -o -name \*.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find-dired` to specify the `find` arguments you need. So, starting from the directory you want to search in:

- M-x `find-dired` RET
- `-name \*.json -o -name \*.txt` RET

Answer (score 3):

> I need this because then I want to delete all find files.

Easy to do if you know some ELisp.

```lisp
(mapcan #'delete-file
        (directory-files-recursively
         "./"  ; current directory
         (concat ".+\\.\\("
                 (mapconcat #'identity
                            [  ; Here's what you want to del
                             "txt"   ; <--
                             "json"  ; <--
                             ]
                            "\\|")
                 "\\)\\'")))
```